# How to show new window when href from Edge IE Mode to Edge

Tags: internet-explorer

In Edge IE Mode, when a new window is forced to appear on MS Edge, it is added to a new tab rather than a pop-up.

How to show new window when href from Edge IE Mode to Edge??

---add--
If i have to force Edge to run in IE Mode, I want to pop up in a new window rather than a new tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOW95.png

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
    location.href = 'microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com';
}

function popup(){
  let options = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,menubar=no";
  window.open("microsoft-edge:"+"https://www.google.com", options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">href direct</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="test();">location</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="popup();">window open</a><br>
<br>
<a href="microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">onclick</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you don't configure the site in the IE mode list, it will open the site in Microsoft Edge instead of Edge IE mode by default.

Second, if you need to open a new window, you can add height and width to the `windowFeatures` parameter in `window.open()`, like this:

```
function popup() {
    let options = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,menubar=no,height=450,width=720";
    window.open("https://www.google.com","Popup", options);
 }
```

Comment: Thx for first answer. If i have to force Edge to run in IE Mode, I want to pop up in a new window rather than a new tab. Look at the attached image (blue box section), when I force  Edge with windows.open, it does not appear as a new window. Then opens as a new tab, and remain tab to force Edge. ToT /  I must use.. "microsoft-edge:" in herf....

Comment: You mean the page you want to open via `window.open()` is also Edge IE mode? If so, I'm afraid it can't be achieved. You need to configure it through [browser settings](edge://settings/defaultBrowser) or corresponding [group policy configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies). But if you just need to open a new Edge window from Edge IE mode website, just use the method I mentioned will be ok.